# Can't include scss file in the css nuxt.config.js configuration

Tags: nuxt.js

I am trying to include a scss file in the css nuxt.config.js option however when I run

```
npm run dev
```

I get the following error :

```
This dependency was not found:

* ..\assets\css\main.scss in ./.nuxt/App.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save ..\assets\css\main.scss
```

Here is my package.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.0.0-rc.11",
    "nuxt": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.1",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-friendly-formatter": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0"
  }
```

And the css configuration :

```
css: [
    "@/assets/css/main.scss",
  ],
```

The main.scss file is located under assets/css/main.scss :

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

* {
  font-family: "Quicksand";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole config file? It may be you are missing a curly brace or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets#sass) points out, verify that you installed `sass-loader`, `sass` and `fibers` (npm packages).

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader fibers
```

verify url path and check whether the file exists in the specified url

```
css: [
    '@/assets/scss/main.scss'
]
```

you could use [style-resources-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module)

refer [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-i-use-scss-variables-mixins-functions-globally-in-nuxt-js-projects-while-compiling-css-utilit-58bb6ff30438)

Comment: This solution didnt work for me, i still get the error